# Comparing lists obtained as output of a 'for' loop, removing duplicate lists from the collection of 30 lists

Tags: excel, python-3.x, list, uitableview, web-scraping

I have 30 statements(strings) at index position from 0 to 29. I want to compare each statement to the rest of the statements and find if there is any exact match. I want to run a loop where each statement, from index position 0 to 29, compares itself one-by-one with every other statement and return statements which have their copies.

```
from itertools import chain
concatenated = chain(range(0, i-1, 1), range(i+1, 30, 1))

def num_cool(i):
    for n in concatenated:
        if (all[i].text) == (all[n].text):        
            print (all[i].text)            
        else:
            print ("Unique")

print (num_cool(11))  
### I have to put the index position('11' here) manually, I just want it to run in a loop for every statement from 0 to 29 and tell which index position(statement) has a repetition at which index position(statement)###

# The result it gives is:

Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
'A' represents the daughter cells formed by X. 'B' represents the daughter cells formed by Y. X and Y are types of cell division, identify them.


'A' represents the daughter cells formed by X. 'B' represents the daughter cells formed by Y. X and Y are types of cell division, identify them.


'A' represents the daughter cells formed by X. 'B' represents the daughter cells formed by Y. X and Y are types of cell division, identify them.


Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
Unique
None
```

#

######This is the complete code

```
import mechanize
import requests
import cookiejar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
from itertools import chain

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar


# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('https://tllms.com/users/sign_in')

# View available forms
for f in br.forms():
    print (f)

# Select the second (index one) form (the first form is a search query box)
br.select_form(nr=0)

# User credentials
br.form['user[login]'] = 'yas********.com'
br.form['user[password]'] = '************'

# Login
br.submit()

c = (br.open('https://tllms.com/admin/questions?order=id_desc&q%5Braw_question_title_cont%5D=cell+division').read())

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all=soup.find_all("td",{"class":"col col-title"})
for n in range(0, 30, 1):
    list1 = [(all[n].text.replace("\xa0","").replace("\n"," "))]    
    print (list1)

<post https://tllms.com/users/sign_in application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(utf8=✓) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(authenticity_token=KlGuEbmgiYkQvlgQvnDAM+oNYooKsalSjXgjMyVNDFE2u20xeYRPQD3SdDaIqqcMxkC1GiDtcZOqL6lUyJOkJg==) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(user[login]=)>
  <PasswordControl(user[password]=)>
  <SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
['Eukaryotic cell division is more complex than prokaryotic cell division because']
['Prokaryotic organisms undergo cell division by']
['The condition in which there is a gain or loss of chromosome(s) due to failure in segregation of chromatids during cell division is called.']
['The failure of chromosomes to separate during cell division is known as.']
['The failure of chromosomes to separate during cell division is known as.']
['P is present in fruits and seeds andit promotes cell division. Y is responsible for wilting of leaves as it inhibits growth. Identify P and Y. ']
['Identify the pair that is correctly matched from the given.  Auxin – cell division Gibberellin – internodal elongation Cytokinin – fruit ripening Ethylene – apical dominance ']
['Karan observed the cell division in amoeba and had drawn the following diagram. Which of the following statements are correct with respect to the diagram?']
['Karan observed the cell division in amoeba and had drawn the following diagram. Which of the following statements are correct with respect to the diagram?']
['The failure of chromosomes to separate during cell division is known as: ']
['Primary oocyte is formed by which type of cell division?']
["'A' represents the daughter cells formed by X. 'B' represents the daughter cells formed by Y. X and Y are types of cell division, identify them.  "]
["'A' represents the daughter cells formed by X. 'B' represents the daughter cells formed by Y. X and Y are types of cell division, identify them.  "]
["'A' represents the daughter cells formed by X. 'B' represents the daughter cells formed by Y. X and Y are types of cell division, identify them.  "]
['Centrioles duplicate during _______ to facilitate cell division.']
['Before cell division, the chromosome number _____________.']
['Centrioles duplicate during _______ to facilitate cell division.']
['Before cell division, the chromosome number _____________.']
['Cell division in asexual reproduction of bacteria is']
['The eukaryotic cell division is assisted by centrosome.']
['A plant shoot’s growth in length is due to cell division in the']
['All living beings possess the capacity of cell division.']
['New cells for growth and reproduction are formed by the process of cell division.']
['All living beings possess the capacity of cell division.']
['New cells for growth and reproduction are formed by the process of cell division.']
['Cell division in asexual reproduction of bacteria is']
['Assertion (A):Cancer cells are virtually immortal until the bodyin which they reside dies. Reason (R):Cancer is caused by damage to genes regulating the cell division cycle. ']
['Meristematic cells undergoes rapid cell division.']
['The failure of chromosomes to separate during cell division is known as: ']
['between homologous chromosomes is a highlight of meiotic cell division.']
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? What does not work?

Comment: If you look at the output, I'm getting 30 lists. A few of them are duplicates of each other. I want only the unique lists, the duplicates need not be there.

Comment: Why is each string inside its own list? You could make a set of strings. Sets are like lists, but they remove duplicates.

Comment: The code works fine till here. I just need to separate the unique lists from this collection.

Comment: A list generally holds multiple items. Try this: `full_set = {all[n].text.replace("\xa0","").replace("\n"," ") for n in range(30)}`

Comment: Thaaaaaank youuuu bro...... The code worksss. Thanks a lott dude.

Comment: No problem. Glad it works.

Comment: The output I'm getting right now in in the format {'string1', 'string2', 'string3'..}. Any way I can turn this again into a list? Or separate strings?

Comment: full_list = list(full_set)